# how to print a pdf with Japanese letters on org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex

I'm trying to print a pdf file which has Japanese letters on org-mode.
I use macbook pro and I installed MacTex 2016 and updated all the programs after installation.

I typed "C-c C-e l o" to make a pdf file.
I can export English letters, but I cannot export Japanese ones.
Do you know how to embed Japanese letters in a pdf file?

I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: Try to export to latex (C-c C-e l l) and then compiling the latex file to PDF, to see what latex has to say.

Comment: This is out of ability of org-mode. You need to setup the LaTeX template to use the jpdflatex or xelatex to compile your file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use latex but Chinese users of my setup use latex.

They reported only XeLaTex supports unicode.

You'd better use org 8 (bundled with Emacs 24.4) instead of org 7 (Emacs 24.3)

Besides, you need specify the font in your setup. Check this setup https://kuanyui.github.io/2014/05/10/emacs-org-mode-xelatex-output-chinese-pdf/. Looks you need tweak `org-latex-classes`. Please note fixed width font is recommended.

Since East Asians share the same HanZi problem, this solution should also work for Japanese.